# How to distinguish noise from an actual change in an image?

Tags: image, image-processing, noise, standard-deviation

I'm trying to see changes between two static photos with slightly different lighting. The problem is i'm not sure whether the change between photos is caused by noise or an actual change in photos.

I tried calculating the noise by taking one hundred photos with exactly the same settings and then calculating standard deviation using means from each photo's histogram. This way I've calculated three standard deviations for red, green and blue parts of the pixel.
Having these three deviations, what I did next was I found means of standard deviations between my test photo (photo with a different lighting) and each photo from the previous step.

In theory, I thought I should have gotten standard deviations close to the noise, however the results were unpredictable and even with a photo which had very minor changes in the lighting (the camera should not have noticed them (i'm using my laptop's camera to do the tests)) I've gotten standard deviations way above the noise limit, which leads me to believe i am doing something wrong. Is there any way to distinguish the noise from actual changes using photo's histograms?

A control photo: 
[image: A control photo]

Very slightly changed photo:
[image: Very slightly changed photo]

Comment: You forgot to add the photos to your question :-)

Comment: “the camera should not have noticed them” I can see the difference between those two photos by eye, I’m sure the camera noticed the difference!

Comment: Please show your code, it will clarify exactly what you did. For example, it is not clear to me if you computed the standard deviation of one photo or of the difference between two photos.

Comment: Standard deviation of the whole picture, doesn't give you the noise at all! because 
there are lots of variation in intensities in different parts of the image. You must crop a homogeneous region of the image (like the empty section of the table) then do what you did on that region. But still there is a question: What change do you care about? geographic change? light change? objects relocation? or what?

Comment: If you are going to detect any change in enviriment, supposing your camera has no movement, simply subtract two subsequent frames. If the change is as small as a single pixel, its impossible to be distinguished from noise, but if its large enough, its not hard to remove noise and detect the change.